# GetFile error in Nifi: Directory does not exist

Tags: apache-nifi

I installed Nifi image docker in a VM Ubuntu. I've tried to get one xml file using GetFile processor, however when I set up the Input Directory field with specific directory created in the Ubuntu returns a error message like this:

Input Directory validated against '/home/john/nifi/inputs' is invalid because Directory does not exist

Is correct type path like this /home/john/nifi/inputs or between ${absolute path}?

Thank very much

Comment: NiFi is in docker image then the path will be docker path, not the host. You should create the folder inside the docker image and map the folder with docker and host.

Comment: If is there a file system host with permissions?

Comment: NiFi cannot recognize the path of the host. Your `home/john/nifi/inputs` is the path of host machine, the Ubuntu. But GetFile processor of NiFi will try to find the path in docker image.

Answer (score 1):

Enter to the Docker container with "**docker exec -it <name_container> /bin/bash**"

Then "**cd ~**" to go to the your the nifi home folder: /home/nifi

So, you are set. Create the folder input with **mkdir**